# Job artifacts are not shown

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using self-hosted gitlab version 14.10 with self-registered gitlab runners using docker executors. In this image I'm using gitlab's secret detection job [template](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/Secret-Detection.gitlab-ci.yml) and it generates artifact `gl-secret-detection-report.json` and it seems that it uploads it back to some kind of coordinator (I wonder what is this) but unfortunately I still can't see it in my `Job artifacts` section at this page.

I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528332/can-t-find-my-artifacts-with-gitlab-ci) question that seemed to be similar, but its not, I've also checked GitLab's documentation and found nothing similar to my issue.

[image]

I even can't see Artifacts column in the Job's list at my Pipeline's page:

[image]

Comment: Could you amend your question to include your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, please?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I've found the answer [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/artifacts_reports.html):

> To be able to browse the report output files, include the artifacts:paths keyword.

After I've overrided artifacts section for the job it worked fine. There's still no "Artifacts" column in the Job's row at the Pipeline's job list page.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

include:
  - project: 'devops/gitlab-templates'
    ref: master
    file: '/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Docker/Docker-Build-Risky.DO.yml'

  - project: 'devops/gitlab-templates'
    ref: master
    file: '/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Security/Trivy-Scan.yml'

  - template: Security/Secret-Detection.gitlab-ci.yml

  - project: 'devops/gitlab-templates'
    ref: master
    file: '/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Security/Dive-Scan.yml'

  - project: 'devops/gitlab-templates'
    ref: master
    file: '/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Docker/Docker-Retag-n-Push.DO.yml'

  - project: 'devops/gitlab-templates'
    ref: master
    file: '/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Docker/Docker-Retag-n-Push.AWS.yml'

  - project: 'devops/gitlab-templates'
    ref: master
    file: '/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Docker/Docker-Retag-n-Push.GCP.yml'

  - project: 'devops/gitlab-templates'
    ref: master
    file: '/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/AWS/Deploy.yml'

secret_detection:
  variables:
    SECRET_DETECTION_HISTORIC_SCAN: "true"
  allow_failure: false
  artifacts:
    reports:
      secret_detection: gl-secret-detection-report.json
    # this is the way to make artifacts appear 
    paths:
      - gl-secret-detection-report.json
    expire_in: 1 day      

integration-tests:
  stage: test
  needs:
    - job: "docker-build"
      artifacts: true
  ...

deploy-to-aws:
  environment: production
  variables:
    ...
```

Comment: @Richard I thought its better to put it in my answer